# Can not get textfield value fetched from MySQL in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I created a model in django like below.

```
class MyDB(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Date added"),editable=True, auto_now_add=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True,null=True)
    text = models.TextField(_("Text"))
```

Then I got the model and mapped into Frontend.

## in views.py file

```
context['mydb'] = MyDB.objects.all()
```

## in HTML file

```
let plots = [];
{% for d in mydb %}
    var id = '{{ d.id }}';
    var title = '{{ d.title }}';
    var text = '{{ d.text }}';        
    console.log(text)
        
{% endfor %}
```

When  the text contains 'enter' in string. it raise error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace ' with ` (backtick), it should fix your issue
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings)